# JavaScript code to include Maximum and minimum limit for a number Z

Tags: javascript

```
function add(id,value)
{
var x  = document. get Element By Id(id). value ;
x = x.replace('$','');
x  = x.replace(',','');
var y = value;
var z = +x + +y;    
document.get Element By Id(id). value =z;
}
```

To set a minimum value for z as 0 and maximium value as 999999999

Comment: What is the question? Where are you stuck? What are you asking for help with? *(What's with the odd spaces in your code?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to make sure `z` is never less than `0` or greater than `999999999`, there are two common ways:

1. Using `if`:

   ```
   if (z < 0) {
       z = 0;
   }
   else if (z > 999999999) {
       z = 999999999;
   }
   ```
2. Using `Math`:

   ```
   z = Math.max(0, Math.min(z, 999999999));
   ```

   `Math.min(z, 999999999)` will pick the smallest of the values you give it, and so won't return a value greater than `999999999`. Similarly, `Math.max(0, ...)` will return the *largest* of the two values you give it, and so won't return a value less than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious solution to this would be

```
if (z > 999999999) {
  z = 999999999;
}else if (z < 0) {
  z = 0;
};
```

Insert this between `var z = +x + +y;` and `document.get Element By Id(id). value =z;`